# TFS200019 Error in TFS: Project already exists

Tags: tfs

When I try to create a new project, I get the error below.   It states that the project exists, but it's nowhere to be found.   I get this when trying to create any new project with different names.

*TF200019: The following project already exists on the Team Foundation Server: Workflow Development.   You cannot create a new project with the same name as an existing project.   Provide a different name.*

Any suggestions?   The discussions online around this don't provide much help.

thanks

Comment: Do you mean you got this error whatever the name you enter for a team project?  Which version of TFS are you using? Which version of VS/Team Explorer are you using? Are you able to create a team project before? Try to clean the cache folder under `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache` to see whether it is helpful.

Comment: Hello -  Yes, we get this error every time we enter a name for a team project.   This is for VS 2015.   We've already tried clearing the cache, but that didn't work.  thanks.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Can other team member create a team project? Are you able to create a team project before? Are you able to create a team project on web protal: `http://tfs2015:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin`?

Comment: Sorry I meant TFS 2015, not VS 2015.    I think I may have narrowed down the issue a bit.   I'm able to create projects using the CMMI process template, but it appears that the error happens when using some custom template that was set up by our devs.    thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your issue is caused by your custom process template. You could create a new team project collection and use the default process template. Also, you could compare the default process template with the custom one, to see which part is different and caused this issue.

Comment: You're right..problem is with the custom template.    We were able to take a newer CMMI template and customize it back to the way we wanted it and it worked.   Thanks!